# Get the chmod numerical value for a file

Tags: linux, freebsd, chmod

In FreeBSD and also in Linux, how can I get the numerical `chmod` value of a file? For example, `644` instead of `-rw-r--r--`? I need an automatic way for a Bash script.

Comment: Similar: [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/71585)

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You can get the value directly using a stat output format, e.g.

Linux:

```
stat --format '%a' <file>
```

BSD/OS X:

```
stat -f "%OLp" <file>
```

Busybox:

```
 stat -c '%a' <file>
```

Comment: single quotes are not needed, and `--format` can be abbreviated `-c`. This works: `stat -c %a <file>`

Comment: I needed the busybox answer on Ubuntu, otherwise 'stat: cannot read file system information for '%OLp': No such file or directory'

Comment: I use `lubuntu`, have `busybox` and `stat -c` gives the result, but `-f` spits out error and prints blocks and inodes info, similar to tofutim.

Answer (score 14):

use `stat YOUR_FILE` unless write script  that calculate :

```
rwx rwx rwx ==> ( r = 4 ) if set + ( w = 2) if set + (x = 1) if set , for example:
You have :
-rw-wxrw- => (4+2+0)(0+2+1)(4+2+0) = 0636 
First argument before 9 permissions is one of :
- = regular file
d =  directory
b = block device
c = character device
s = socket
p = pipe
f = fifo
```

By the way , I use `stat command` on `Linux box`, not `freebsd`, because it investigate `HFS` probably work with `UFS`.

Comment: Yes, i found it under `FreeBSD box`, use `stat -x YOUR_FILE` under `FreeBSD box`

Comment: `stat -r YOUR_FILE |awk '{print $3}' ` gives your permission.

Comment: command to show friendly? not only a number like `666`  or codes `-rw-wxrw-`  but a text with explanations about each permission.

Comment: @PeterKrauss , It's better to write an `awk` to retrive numerical result.

Comment: Thanks @PersianGulf. Hum... No plug-and-play standard way....

Comment: You forgot the `l` and please, your homepage in english;) we are global people..

Answer (score 12):

Some additional information on [`stat`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/stat.htm):

```
$ stat -c %a file.txt

777  

$ stat -c %A file.txt

-rwxrwxrwx
```

Comment: it is `stat -f %A file.txt` under mac, it would return 644 or some other 3 digital number.

Comment: this works, the others answers not `stat (GNU coreutils) 8.28`

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `stat`, try this to get the value for all non-hidden files in the current working directory.

```
stat --format "%a  %n" -- *
```